# Livewire wire:click, wire:model not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

i wrire a sample code to test livewire action but not work

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Frontend\Ticket;
use Livewire\Component;
class Ticket extends Component
{
    
    public function submit()
    {
        dd('ok');
    }

}
```

and component:

```
@extends('frontend.layouts.app')
@section('content')
 <div>
        <button wire:click="submit" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
 </div>
@endsection
```

what is problem? i added `@livewireStyles` and `@livewireScripts`

Comment: seems u did everything correct. Did u created the component with the artisan command?

Comment: yes i create with artisan command @MauroCelentano

Comment: i think submit is a reserved word, try changing with a random name

Comment: Publish livewire related assets then try again.

Comment: can you see any error in console? any network request is done on click?

Answer (score 0):

just try to use this

```
<button wire:click="submit($event.target.value)" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
```

try to add this `($event.target.value)`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31252614)